# How to change the default/preferred SSL cipher in Linux?

Tags: tls, openssl, cipher-selection, ciphers

Is there any way I could change the default/preferred cipher for SSL, so that any application/process in Linux which uses SSL would have to use that specific cipher (RC4-SHA for example) for it's connection to the outside world?

I am using Xen hypervisor in Ubuntu 14.04 and I have installed `openssl`. Xen can use SSL in order to "securely" migrate (transfer) a VM to another host in the LAN. I need to be able to change the preferred/default SSL cipher and do some tests.

Answer (score 3):

There are various SSL stacks used in Linux: NSS for the Firefox and Chrome and usually OpenSSL for the rest. While OpenSSL has its DEFAULT ciphers which are compiled into the library several users of OpenSSL use their own cipher sets. Notably languages like Python, Perl, Ruby have all their own preferred cipher sets coded into their various libraries.

Which means, that there is no central place where you could change the ciphers used by all application. You have to do it mostly for each application separately.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Thanks for the help anyway